# Why does foreground job ignore job control signals when Bash is running as PID 1?

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals, job-control

When `bash` is invoked as **pid 1** directly through the kernel option `init=/bin/bash --login`, it will issue something like this before prompting:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

And **no keyboard-generated signals (e.g ^Z, ^C, ^\) work.**

To solve this problem, I wrote a simple program `init1.c` as following:

```c
/* init1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *options[] = {"--login", NULL};
  int tty_fd = -1;

  printf("\n----- Bash Init 1 -----\n\n");

  /* Make bash as session leader. */
  if (setsid() == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "setsid()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Make /dev/tty1 as controlling terminal of Bash. */
  tty_fd = open("/dev/tty1", O_RDWR);
  if (tty_fd == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "open()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Re-connect stdin, stdout, stderr to the controlling terminal. */
  dup2(tty_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
  close(tty_fd);
  
  execv("/bin/bash", options);
}
```

Compiled it as `init1`, then invoked it as **pid 1** (i.e Bash running as **pid 1**), the preceding error messages disappear and some signals (e.g ^C, ^\) work, but job control signals (e.g ^Z) still not (unexpected).

So to make job control signals work, I revised the code above as `init2.c` (just `fork()`):

```c
/* init2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *options[] = {"--login", NULL};
  pid_t pid = -1;
  int tty_fd = -1;
  
  printf("\n----- Bash Init 2 -----\n\n");
  
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "fork()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
  /* Parent. */
  if (pid > 0)
   {
     /* Wait for its child, otherwise all processes would be killed ! */
     while (wait(NULL) > 0)
       ;
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
      
  /* Child. */
  if (setsid() == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "setsid()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        
  
  /* Make /dev/tty1 as controlling terminal of Bash. */
  tty_fd = open("/dev/tty1", O_RDWR);
  if (tty_fd == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "open()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Re-connect stdin, stdout, stderr to the controlling terminal. */
  dup2(tty_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
  close(tty_fd);
  
  execv("/bin/bash", options);
}
```

Compiled it as `init2` and invoked as **pid 1** (i.e. finally Bash running as arbitrary PID other than 1), and this time, the job control signals work!

But I didn't figure out why the job control signals work in `init2` (Bash isn't **pid 1**) but not `init1` (Bash is **pid 1**), why does foreground job ignore job control signals when Bash is running as PID 1? It seems that there is something special with **pid 1**.

---

### Update 3/21/2022:

Recently, I found a very simple shell [mysh](https://github.com/hungys/mysh) in github which also implements **job control**, only **949** lines! When I ran it with `init1` and `init2`, this shell also has the same problem! (Thanks to it, I don't have to read the complicated `bash` source code for figuring out my question. Orz) And the problem lies in `waitpid()` which doesn't return immediately when **SIGTSTP(^Z)** reaches. So this issue is not only relative to `bash`, but also the shells that implement **job control**. However, I don't understand why does't `waitpid()` return if **SIGTSTP** reaches when shell is running as **PID 1**... 囧

Comment: I'd use `dup2()` to reassign fds 0, 1, and 2 instead of `close()` and `dup()`.  RIght now, if `open("/dev/tty1", O_RDWR)` fails your error message is lost.  You also missed reopening standard error.

Comment: How are you getting bash to run as pid 1?  Is it the main process in a docker container?

Comment: @dbush Not a docker container. I just use kernel parameter `init=`.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thanks for your advice, I have revised my code. :）

Comment: The signals are there, but for PID 1 process, kernel sets the signal handlers for most "terminate by default" signals to be "ignore by default". The process can, of course, override those at its own discretion.

Comment: **Do not** do this! The `init` process (e.g. `systemd`) has to do many things mount file systems, start networking, etc. And, do a clean system shutdown. `bash` knows nothing about this. To get a shell, boot the system in emergency/singleuser mode. You risk corrupting your system. Do this only in a VM with your method. Or, boot a USB stick

Comment: @Craig Estey I really do this in VirtualBox. Don't Worry ... :-)

Comment: I've done this before in systems shipped to customers but I used `perl` because it's more self contained

Comment: I learn `GNU\Linux` just for fun, that's all... :-)

Comment: To OP: Please see [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990) on when *not* to use `code` formatting for emphasis.

Comment: To the OP: did you read `man 2 kill` ? Please do so.

Comment: @wildplasser I have read it just now. But as I known, all keyboard signals are sent to the foreground process group only. In this case, `bash`(as **pid 1**) and its child process are in the different process group, right ?

Answer (score 3):

In linux, processes are given default signal handlers. A variety of signals (like `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`), have the default behavior of immediately exiting.

For historical and system reasons, pid 1 just does not get these default signal handlers defined, so there's no behavior there. Note that this doesn't stop you from redefining signal handlers yourself.

From the [linux kernel man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html)

> Only signals for which the "init" process has established a
> signal handler can be sent to the "init" process by other members
> of the PID namespace.  This restriction applies even to
> privileged processes, and prevents other members of the PID
> namespace from accidentally killing the "init" process.
>
> Likewise, a process in an ancestor namespace can—subject to the
> usual permission checks described in kill(2)—send signals to the
> "init" process of a child PID namespace only if the "init"
> process has established a handler for that signal.  (Within the
> handler, the siginfo_t si_pid field described in sigaction(2)
> will be zero.)  SIGKILL or SIGSTOP are treated exceptionally:
> these signals are forcibly delivered when sent from an ancestor
> PID namespace.  Neither of these signals can be caught by the
> "init" process, and so will result in the usual actions
> associated with those signals (respectively, terminating and
> stopping the process).

Comment: No. I think this problem isn't relative to the concept of `PID namespaces`. One use of `namespaces` is to implement `containers`. As per [pid_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html), the creation of a new `PID namespace` using `clone()` with the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag. I even not use these things to create a process and neither do kernel, let alone a `PID namespace`.